# Tracking exceptions on AddObject in Entity Framework with Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception

Suppose I have codes like these

```
public void Upload (Picture picture)
   try
        {
          //ps is the entity framework
            ps.AddToPictures(picture);
            ps.SaveChanges();

            return picture.PictureId;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //some codes to bound the exception to the model 
        }
```

How can I present the exceptions to the model and present them in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ModelState.AddError**.

Example:

```
catch (Exception e) {
   ModelState.AddError("SomeErrorKey", e.Message);
}
```

Then in the View:

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("SomeErrorKey") %>
```

Can't remember the correct overload for ValidationMessage - so take a look at the different overloads.

I'd recommend using custom exceptions though - you don't want to display things like "Null reference exception" in your View.

More on ModelState.AddError [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/performing-simple-validation-cs).

Comment: @Seen - No problems - let us know how you get on.